# How to set application in port mode only?

Tags: android

How to set application in port mode only?
I does not wanna when phone landscape is on my application should still work in port mode dose not change to land mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your manifest file for your Activity to restrict the application to Portrait mode:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.package.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnxs! ones again :)

Comment: yha sure i will accept it but i cant accept it before 8 mints as stackoverflow does not give me permission to do that :P

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the MANIFEST file, where you declare your Activity.

Set the `screenOrientation` property to `portrait`, like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your application mode using AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Or you can do it programatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your APP MANIFEST file,

Set `screenOrientation` property to `portrait`,:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```